finite Borel measures $\mu$ on the real line such that $L_1(\mu)$ is finite
This might be a basic question, but I haven't found any information about this in my books. Is there a way to describe all the finite Borel measures $\mu$ on the real line such that $L_1(\mu)$ is finite? Is there any way to check this easily?
Thanks in advance!

$L_1(μ)$ is a vector space. It cannot be a finite set unless it is just {0}. This is possible only if $μ(E)=0$ or $∞$ for any measurable set $E$.

Consider:

Finite Total Measure: $ \mu $ must be a finite measure, i.e., $ \mu(\mathbb{R}) < \infty $.

Support and Decay: If $ \mu $ has compact support or, if supported on all of $ \mathbb{R} $, has a density function with sufficient decay at infinity, then $ L^1(\mu) $ will be finite.


To check, ensure $ \mu(\mathbb{R}) < \infty $ and that any density function $ f $ of $ \mu $ satisfies $ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)| \, dx < \infty $. Compact support of $ \mu $ also implies $ L^1(\mu) $-finiteness.

Even for Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, this space is infinite dimensional.
